# c# convert a string of 1's and 0's to a sequence of bits

Tags: c#, image, compression, huffman-code

I am currently involved in image compression using Huffman model. At this point I have achieved compression and decompression but there is the following problem:
I use a text file to store the ones and zeros. However this is not really a compression as I need to store the ones and zeros as bits and not ascii characters. So the question is how do I convert a string of 1 and 0 into a sequence of bits? Attention: every 1 and 0 is a simple bit. Example: "10" into 10 as bits.

P.S. The language Iam using is C#

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "into 10 as bits"? It would really help if you'd give concrete code with input and expected output, including the *types* of the output. (Do you want a result of `byte[]` where each 8 characters is one `byte` for example?) Do you really need to store text at all? (My guess is that your idea of "ascii characters" isn't quite mine...)

Comment: I'm pretty sure from the context he means that "10101010" should be a byte with the bits 10101010 (though it's not defined what the behavior should be if the string length is not a multiple of 8).  Again from context, a byte[] seems appropriate.

Comment: SO is not somewhere to ask "can you supply me code to solve my problem?" questions, so voting to close.

Comment: @Dave Jon was right...Do you really need to store txt?...Why not write to a binary file? Check out System.IO.BinaryWriter class here --> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: If you want to "convert a string to an array of bits" then you can use [System.Collection.BitArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Just parse the string into a bool array (you should know how to do this) I don't think that's actually what you're asking though.

Comment: No, text file can be avoided. I used it as help to see if the code works. I have strings which look like "1","10","101",...,"1001101" they don't create a byte and I would like to avoid ,if possible, joining them as a puzzle to make a byte. Well, these strings need to be stored to a file (in general). So my question is a string a="10011010100001011010001" (random) to be stored as 10011010100001011010001 (a binary number). Hope this helps.